# DNS ends with ::1

Tags: dns, ip, ip-address, setup

This is probably a very basic and silly question but why does my DNS server end with `::1`.  I don’t even know if redirect or repurpose is the right word but is someone else directing my internet?

I’ve got like 3-4 different connections going somehow and I don’t know what I’ve done.

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 address for localhost.  I doubt you're under attack.  What OS?

Comment: @squillman is right. That's normal, and it's IPv6.

Comment: So that implies that you have DNS resolver software on your system to handle DNS queries, and this configuration allows your applications to send queries to that software for results without really knowing that they are doing so. The apps just think they are making a DNS query. That in turn allows your system to use multiple types of name resolution (like mDNS if it is in a zero-conf environment).

Comment: Gosh that all seems so busy.   It's a windows 11 pc.   Just a little pc for emails or general browsing, etc.   So I'm localhost?   local meaning my pc.    I'll do some ore studying.    Thank you all very much.   I jst wanted to be sure m PC had some autonomy from the wifi owner

Answer (score 1):

Double colons (::) in IPv6 is a shorthand of a series of zeros. If your DNS server's IPv6 address is `123:abc::1`, then it can be written as `123:abc:0:0:0:0:0:1`. Usually localhost is represented as `::1` in IPv6, so it is also written as `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=concepts-ipv6-address-formats

Also, when you add a port number to an IPv6 address, the address is enclosed in square brackets, then follows a colon and a port number (e.g. `[123:abc::1]:80`).